# Mac OS X Lion Ant Eclipse JBPM Java Error

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, ant, jbpm

I am trying to proceed a comand from Terminal:

```
ant start.demo
```

and the following problem occurs in the building process:

> BUILD FAILED /Users/iaevgenia/Documents/jbpm-installer/build.xml:846: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse": error=13, Permission denied

What should I do?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's obvious. Add proper permissions to `./eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse`